Can someone help me with a simple quotient rule problem
If $V(t) = \frac{3}{(t^2-2t)^2}$, what is $v'(-1)$?
I got $\frac{8}{9}$ as my answer but it is wrong. I used quotient rule and got $$\frac{3(-4t+4)^{-3}}{(t^2-2t)^2}$$ What am I doing wrong? First I took the first derivtive then the second!

It’s impossible to tell what you actually did. First, the quotient rule would require that you square the denominator. Second, it would require that the constant $3$ appear. Don’t use the quotient rule. Use the power rule directly.

Treat $t^2-2t$ as a single function. Use the power rule and then multiply it by $2t-2$

@TedShifrin I used power rule to get the derivative of g(x) for my quotient rule. Which I got as -2(2t-2)^-3

If you write $V(t)=3(t^2-2t)^{-2}$, then you can use the power rule directly. Then figure out what you did wrong.

@Gwen could you elaborate please?

@TedShifrin I used power rule and got  -6(2t-2)^-3. I rewrote it as -6/ (2t-3) ^-3. I plugged in for -1 and I still don't think I came up with the right answer. Is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

Please use MathJax to format mathematics.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  Failing to do so makes it much harder to read what you're writing, which is inconsiderate when you're asking volunteers to help.

The power rule includes the chain rule for the derivative of the “inside function.”

$V(t)=3(t^2-2t)^{-2}=3u^{-2}$, where $u=t^2-2t$.  Now use the power rule and the chain rule:
$V'(t)=\dfrac{dV(t)}{dt}=\dfrac{dV}{du} \dfrac {du}{dt} = -6u^{-3}\dfrac{du}{dt}$.  Since $\dfrac{du}{dt}=2t-2=2(t-1)$, we have $V'(t)=-12(t-1)(t^2-2t)^{-3}$.
Thus, $V'(-1)=\dfrac{(-12) \cdot (-2)}{3^3}=\dfrac{24}{27}=\dfrac 89.$  What makes you think your answer was wrong?
